# Undefined type Aws\S3\S3Client how to fix it. Me use PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i tried a system s3 object storage from idrive and i did composer install for composer require aws/aws-sdk-php.

but it shows error like that in my code window.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK53h.png)

```
<?php

require "../vendor/autoload.php";

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

// Create an S3 client for IDrive e2
$profile_credentials = [
    "profile" => "default",
    "endpoint" => "l4g4.ch11.idrivee2-2.com",
    "region" => "Chicago",
    "version" => "latest",
    "use_path_style_endpoint" => true,
];
$s3 = S3Client::factory($profile_credentials);

// Get list of buckets
try {
    $buckets = $s3->listBuckets();
    // print bucket names
    foreach ($buckets["Buckets"] as $bucket) {
        echo "{$bucket["Name"]}\n";
    }
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    echo "Error: {$e->getMessage()}" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I just want an example for this s3 object strong to work I have also tried things on the amazon aws documentation but haven't found any results and the error keeps coming

Comment: That's your editor complaining that it doesn't know about that class, not PHP.

Comment: Regardless of what it looks like in the IDE, does your code run correctly?